# Twitter Streaming API, how to search in a box AND for a term

Tags: python, api, twitter, streaming

So basically what I want to do is use the streaming API to search for certain emoji but also only pull tweets from within the United STates. Does anyone know how I would go about this? I am using python. Currently I am just pulling all tweets with the emoji and manually going through them to see if the tweets are from the US.

This is my current code:

```
twitterStream.filter(track=["Ossoff"],languages=['en'])
```

What can I add to this so it only searches for the track term in a bounded location? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The relevant API doc is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters). Quoting the doc:

> Bounding boxes do not act as filters for other filter parameters. For example track=twitter&locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8 would match any Tweets containing the term Twitter (even non-geo Tweets) OR coming from the San Francisco area.